# Integration involving greatest integer function : $\int_0^{\pi} [\cot(x)] \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

What the integral of $$\int_0^{\pi} [\cot(x)]dx$$  where $[\cdot]$ represents greatest integer function. I know integral of $\cot$ is $|\log(\sin(x))|$ but $\log$ is not defined for $0$ or is there something else I'm forgetting?

Comment: Hint : the domain of integration starts from pi/4 to 0, and from pi/4 to 3pi/4, the integrand is zero.

Comment: Can you explain futher

Comment: @user230452  The integrand won't be zero. For fractional negative values, the greatest integer function returns $-1$ and not $0$ which is true for positive fractional (less than 1) values.

Comment: This integral does not exist even in improper sense, by the same reason $\int_{0}^{\pi} \cot x \, dx$ does not exist. This is because the integral $$ \int_{0}^{\pi} (\cot x - \lfloor \cot x \rfloor ) \, dx $$ exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Outline**

Observe the symmetry (up to sign) of $\cot x$ about $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

So the fundamental idea we use here is $[\cot x] = -[\cot (\pi - x)] - 1$ when $ x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

So $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} [\cot(x)]\,dx + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} [\cot(\pi - x)]\,dx = -\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 1 \,dx$$ which gives

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^{\pi} [\cot(x)]\,dx = \color{blue}{-\frac{\pi}{2}}}$$