# Solving Integral involving greatest integer function: $\int_{0}^{100}\left[\tan^{-1}x\right] dx$ and $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[\cot^{-1}x\right]dx $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> **Question** Solve (a) $\int_{0}^{100}\left[\tan^{-1}x\right] dx$
>
> $\left(b\right)$ $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[\cot^{-1}x\right]dx $

I have found a [Helpful post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654296/integration-involving-greatest-integer-function-int-0-pi-cotx-dx)

It suggest there are many other formulas like this that may help.Can anyone please tell me what are they or where i can find them ?

**Book's Answer**$\left(a\right)$$\int_{0}^{\tan1}\left[\tan^{-1}x\right]dx$+$\int_{\tan1}^{100}$$\left[\tan^{-1}x\right]$dx=$\int_{0}^{tan1}0.dx$+$\int_{\tan1}^{100}1dx$

But I cannot understand it what is happenning. Please Please Please
Suggest me study material or book. So I can do them myself

Comment: Do you know what the graph of $\tan^{-1}x$ looks like?  Based on that, can you figure out what the graph of $\lfloor\tan^{-1}x\rfloor$ looks like?

Comment: @Mike Brother the question is from a competitive exam of undergraduate level.Am I supposed to be knowing the graph of inverse function without graphics calculator.

Comment: @Mike please help with the formulas similar to the post I mentioned above

Comment: Yes. In a competition you are expected to graph elementary functions mentally without a calculator. Competitions usually are to screen students who have put in extra effort to learn the stuff and then some extras on their own. To do well in those you need to have math as a passionate hobby. Excelling at schoolwork is sorta assumed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), which is denoted by $\lfloor x \rfloor$, gives the greatest integer for the real number $x$.

For the inverse tangent function on the interval $[0,100]$ its value lies between zero and its asymptotic value of $\pi/2$ which it approaches from below (this information comes from knowing what the graph of the inverse tangnet function looks like and is a very important skill to have).

Knowing all this we now need to establish for what values of $x$ is $\tan^{-1} x$ is less than one and for what values of $x$ is $\tan^{-1} x$ greater than one for $x \in [0,100]$.

As the inverse tangent function monotonically increases from zero when $x = 0$ to a value between one and two when $x = 100$ (as $\tan^{-1} (100) < 2$), finding when $\tan^{-1} (x) = 1$ we see this occurs when $x = \tan 1$.

So for our integral we have
\begin{align*}
\int^{100}_0 \lfloor \tan^{-1} x \rfloor \, dx &= \int^{\tan 1}_0 \lfloor \tan^{-1} x \rfloor \, dx + \int^{100}_{\tan 1} \lfloor \tan^{-1} x \rfloor \, dx\\
&= \int^{\tan 1}_0 0 \, dx + \int^{100}_{\tan 1} 1 \, dx\\
&= 100 - \tan 1.
\end{align*}

Your integral for the inverse cotangent function can be now be done in a similar fashion.

Comment: $\tan x=1$ at $x=\frac\pi4$.  If $\tan^{-1}x=1, x=\tan 1$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. My mistake.

Comment: Can you explain the formula I mentioned in helpful post

Comment: @KislayTripathi This is the formula you're looking for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092709/why-does-int-ab-fx-dx-int-ab-fab-x-dx